# Dart coding styles

Tags: oop, coding-style, dart

Maybe this is not a `Dart` specific question.

I have :

```dart
class A {
  int a;

  A(this.a);
}

class B extends A {
  String b;

  B(a, this.b) : super(a);
}
```

So you see, class `A` has an attribute `int a` and `B` just extends `A` and has an extra attribute `String b` and a wrapper class `C` :

```dart
class C {
  A c;

  C(this.c);

  void doSomething() {
    if (c is B) {
      print(c.b);
    } else {
      print(c.a);      
    }
  }

}
```

The Dart Editor complaints that the `c doesn't have a getter b`. How do you deal with this? I want to get rid the warning, but I don't want to add attribute `b` to class `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast expression.

```
print((c as B).b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The analyzer shouldn't add a warning here. I think it's related to this issue : [Analyzer fails to respect certain "is" checks](http://dartbug.com/11080).

In the meanwhile, you can use `(c as B).b` to *cast* `c` in `B`.

Answer (score 2):

`(c as B)` works, but will do a dynamic type check (which will probably be eliminated by the VM).

If you just want to remove the warning, without changing the semantics of the program you can assign to a temporary variable of the correct type:

```dart
void doSomething() {
  if (c is B) {
    B b = c;
    print(b.b);
  } else {
    print(c.a);
  }
}
```